# I keep getting an error with selenium and google forms

Tags: python, forms, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to automate a google form, and I'm doing that by using selenium, but I keep getting an error and I don't know what to do, can anyone provide some assistence? Here is my code:

from selenium import webdriver

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("-incognito")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
#option.add_argument("--headless")
#option.add_argument("disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/19379/Downloads/chromedriver', options=option)

browser.get("https://forms.gle/opNDfNn2uVwUxDCG7")

checkboxes = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseRoot")

checkboxes[1].click()
```

here is my new error after installing the correct selenium version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuXFK.png)

Comment: Download the latest chrome driver 88 or downgrade chrome version to 86. You have a mismatch of versions.

Comment: After installing chrome driver 88 and chrome version 88 it still doesn't work

Comment: What are the errors now.

Comment: I just changed the post to display the new error, thanks

Comment: Did you add the chrome driver to environment variables. Also is that the right path like the absolute path.

Comment: What OS do you work in?

Comment: I'm using mac Catalina,  and I have not added the chrome driver to the environment variables, but I'll try that right now, thank you